# How to set html text to a label Swift

Tags: html, swift, label

I have a String with html content, something like this

```
let content:String = "<p>p1</p><p>p2</p>"
let contentFromHtml = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: content.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil)
label.text = contentFromHtml
```

I can't get the "carriage return"

Comment: What is your question exactly? This code translates this HTML to `"p1\np2"` which is what I would expect from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `label.attributedText`

This property expects an attributedString, just like in your example.